# Typeof for javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, typeof

When I declare a function like this:

```
function x() { return 123 };
```

Then:

```
typeof x; //return "function"
typeof x(); //return "number"
```

That's ok, but once I create a variable like this:

```
var y = function x() { return 123 };
```

It becomes:

```
typeof y; //return "function"
typeof y(); //return "number"
typeof x; //return "undefined"
typeof x(); //return error
```

Why does x lose his function? Please helpp

Comment: I am getting different results..Tried in chrome and mozilla..

Comment: @RayonDabre I don't, I tried both too. What exactly did you try?

Comment: See https://kangax.github.io/nfe/ --- under the headline "Named function expressions" this exact thing is mentioned (end of that section): *"An important detail to remember is that this name is only available in the scope of a newly-defined function; specs mandate that an identifier should not be available to an enclosing scope:"*

Comment: @Pius, check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/0yswpr4w/)

Comment: @RayonDabre  That is completely different. What are you trying to show? Of course your "x()" is defined -- you do so at the top! See my comment and the link above.

Comment: @Mörre Noseshine, Yeah, my mistake..scope changed !

Comment: @MörreNoseshine I think that assigning function declaration to a var is useless, therefore better not to do that, is it true?

Comment: @Pius No wrong. Follow the link, I included it for a reason. It isn't done for the code, it is done for the coder! Try reading a stack trace of anonymous function expressions...

Comment: @MörreNoseshine Mmm I still don't get it, is it done for debugging? why?

Comment: I said two things: a) read the linked article, b) "Try reading a stack trace of anonymous function expressions.." I repeat it now. In addition, recursive functions. See the linked document(!) ----- https://kangax.github.io/nfe/#named-expr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does x lose his function?

A function declaration creates a variable of the same name in the current scope.

A named function expression does not (except in certain older versions of Internet Explorer, which is a bug).

That's just how function expressions are supposed to work.

Comment: I usually say that «function x(){}» is only a shorthand for «var x = function x(){}». The first 'x' is the variable name, which is the name of the variable which holds the function in it's declaration time. The second 'x' is the actual name of the function, which is what you will see in error traces and debugging data despite the variable or method used to call it. …also, function name can be used to call itself (recursively) inside the function whithout caring for if the initial holding variable is deleted or reused.

Comment: *I usually say that «function x(){}» is only a shorthand for «var x = function x(){}».* — Well, it isn't. Aside from all the other differences you've already listed, function declarations are hoisted and function expressions are not.

Comment: @bitifet does it mean that whatever name I use to declare function, it will lose its function if I declare it as a variable in another name? And the function itself will belong to the new variable

Comment: True. I tryed to explain clearly why there is the two forms and did wrong. It is actually not "only" that...

Comment: @Pius — No. Assigning a function to a variable won't remove all other references to it. It's just that creating a function using a function expression won't create a variable of the same name in the current scope.

Comment: @Quentin Oh i see.. once I declare a var with function declaration, it becomes expression?